# Perform function on publish AND save (not just save)

Tags: functions, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, save-post

I am using this function to auto-set a post title based on a couple of custom fields:

```
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'event') {
    $getdate = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'event_datestart',true);
    $dateformat = new DateTime($getdate);
    $date = $dateformat->format( 'm-d-Y' );
    $event_venue = get_post_meta($postarr['ID'],'venue_name',true);
    $event_title = $event_venue . ' - ' . $date;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);
    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '99', 2 );
```

But I can only get it to work on post update and not on the initial publishing of the post. Is there a way to make this work both the FIRST time as well as the rest of the times when the post is saved?

Comment: Just a thought: Will publish fire the same event as save?

Comment: What does your [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking meta values from  get_post_meta function take it from $postarr array because when initial publishing of the post there isn't any values for event_datestart and venue_name in database and it returns empty string.

**Updated Code :**

```
function set_event_title( $data , $postarr ) {
  if($data['post_type'] == 'event') {
    $getdate = $postarr['event_datestart']; // Replace event_datestart with the input field name of event_datestart post meta.
    $dateformat = new DateTime($getdate);
    $date = $dateformat->format( 'm-d-Y' );
    $event_venue = $postarr['venue_name']; // Replace venue_name with the input field name of venue_name post meta.   
    $event_title = $event_venue . ' - ' . $date;
    $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes ($event_title,'','save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_slug);
    $data['post_title'] = $event_title;
    $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;
  }
  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_event_title' , '99', 2 );
```

For more information see [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data).